# MapView crash without log

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a simple activity with just a MapView element. The map is loaded fine but as soon as I zoom in / out the app just crashes without giving me any sort of log (I also tried without the package filter, but anything usefull appeared). The only thing I can suspect is a memory problem, but I don't know how to check and eventually fix it.

Activity:

```
public class PointsOfInterest extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_map);

        /* MapView */
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: same problem with fragment:

Activity:

```
public class PointsOfInterest extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_map);

        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, if I try with "match_parent" instead of 230dp, the app restarts as soon as I move the map or zoom in / out (in other words, when I have to load new map data). The smaller the map is, the longer I can use it.
This makes me think even more to a memory problem (anyway, RAM usage is just 40MB with peaks of 50MB when loading map, with an immediate GC which takes down again to 40MB)

Comment: when you view the logcat, are you setting it to show everything as opposed to just the running app?

Comment: In Android Studio I've tried both "Show only selected application" and "No filter" options. I've aso tried to check the logcat using adb (logcat -d > log.txt) and this is the only thing which seems to regard the crash: I/WindowState(  760): WIN DEATH: Window{74b2951 u0 it.techdt.mycars/it.techdt.mycars.PointsOfInterest.PointsOfInterest}
I/ActivityManager(  760): Process it.techdt.mycars (pid 32400) has died
W/ActivityManager(  760): Force removing ActivityRecord{7164b63 u0 it.techdt.mycars/.PointsOfInterest.PointsOfInterest t20622}: app died, no saved state

Comment: why are you calling `mapView.onCreate` (or any other lifecycle events)? you are not supposed to do that.

Comment: Google documentation and samples explicitly tell to manage the MapView lifecycle (and mapView.onCreate is used to show the map, otherwise it doesn't get loaded and shown): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite#lifecycle

Comment: that is odd. btw, have you seen this on the doc that you linked: `Users viewing the map cannot zoom or pan the map.`

Comment: Sorry I linked you the wrong doc (I'm not using the lite mode). Look here ("users of this class must forward all the activity lifecycle methods to the corresponding methods in the MapView class"): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#mapview

Comment: you don't seem to follow that doc. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to use the map in [lite mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite#lifecycle). The document says that, in that mode, user is not allowed to pan or zoom.

If you really need the pan/zoom functionality, do this instead:

1) Add this fragment to your activity layout xml:

```
...
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
...
```

2) Initialize the map like this on your activity `onCreate`:

```
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the MapView? Apparently I should be able to do that: "MapView, a subclass of the Android View class, allows you to place a map in an Android View. A View represents a rectangular region of the screen, and is a fundamental building block for Android applications and widgets. Much like a MapFragment, the MapView acts as a container for the map, exposing core map functionality through the GoogleMap object."

Comment: Fragment is simpler, why don't you try that and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: I tried but I keep getting the same error also with SupportMapFragment (app restart and no kind of crash log)

Comment: Update your question with the fragment usage.

Comment: Question updated. In the end of the question I've also described a behaviour which may be usefull.

Comment: unless you are doing some other stuff that you are not sharing with us, there is no reason your code should cause a crash.

Comment: I'm not doing anything more than what I've posted; obviously that's an activity inside a bigger project, but it's called like other activity. Anyway I've managed to try it also on a friend device and it was working perfectly. Moreover, after rebooting my Nexus 5 it started working well also there. I'm a bit confused... probably there were some problems with the Google Play services... Thanks for your help!